# What happened to Hopper's girlfriend in season one?

Tags: stranger-things

In one episode in season one we see Hopper in the middle of the night go out to smoke a cigarette. In a few seconds he is joined by a woman who asks him to get back inside. I assume that's his girlfriend. What happened to her?

Was the character written out of the story or is there an in-story explanation why we don't see her any more?

Comment: Stranger things happened to her that you can possibly imagine :)

Comment: @EdmundDantes would be fun though if she just re-appeared.

Comment: I've watched season one twice and season two once and I'd completely forgotten about this character.

Comment: The answer below is good enough. I just think that it's sloppy writing. Why insert her like that and not have an ever so short scene where they broke up or something. I really expected her to pop up later during season one and towards the last episodes I was like "wait, there is someone missing here".

Comment: @Johan It's called world building. We've not met Hopper before, but the fact that he's choosing to stand outside and smoke, instead of spending time with the woman he's slept with, says a lot about Hopper's state of mind when we find him. Remember, Hopper is initially skeptical about Joyce Byers claims, and a major factor driving that is his general apathy about life.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think Fandom got this one right in [their Jim Hopper Entry](https://strangerthings.fandom.com/wiki/Jim_Hopper)

> The loss of his daughter and family life left Hopper emotionally reserved and cynical. To manage his pain, he regularly drank alcohol, smoked several cigarettes a day and developed an addiction to anti-anxiety drugs. Instead of making real connections with people, he slept around with several women who he never contacted again.

The woman in S1E2 is simply there to facilitate the backstory of Hopper. We find out in the course of the season that [Hopper's first daughter Sara](https://strangerthings.fandom.com/wiki/Sara_Hopper) died of cancer. This causes Hopper's marriage to [Diane](https://strangerthings.fandom.com/wiki/Diane) to break up. As such, when we first meet Hopper, he's simply engaging in one-night stands or employing prostitutes. She is [named Sandra](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm3869592/) in both the actress list and the subtitles (and only listed for that one episode). Regardless, the fact that she does not appear in any other episode means she was not important to Hopper.

Comment: Wait, she doesn't appear again? Wasn't she the librarian who Hopper and one of the other policemen came to see shortly after while on duty to inquire about something official, causing an awkward moment for Hopper?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I had to question my own answer and I got the episode wrong (2, not 1). The woman's name is Sandra in the subtitles and actress entry of IMDB (see edit above). The librarian is [Marissa](https://strangerthings.fandom.com/wiki/Marissa)